# Can I sign an .exe that launches another?

Tags: code-signing, authenticode

I'm developing an installer (an .exe) that extracts and launches another installer.  If I use an Authenticode certificate to sign the first .exe, does the embedded installer need to be signed too?  I need to be able to run my installer on various versions of Windows (including Vista with UAC turned on) and the experience needs to be seemless for users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will want to sign all of the .exe files that will eventually run as a part of your ecosystem.  If the "installer within the installer" is an .exe and can get decompressed and executed, Windows will present it's "unknown publisher" dialog if it is not signed.

Comment: Are you sure?  In vista I was able to have a Java .jar launch an exe and I only got an Unknown Publisher dialog when I went to start the Java .jar.